# Dropdown navigation to stay open upon selected

Tags: html, css

I've got a sub nav that I want to stay open when it is clicked. I've got a "ul li a.selected" and I apply the rule "#main_nav ul li a.selected > ul { display: block; }" in place. Where am I faulting here? Specifically on this page, the Location drop down should be active. It's got the class "class="first selected"".

Thanks in advance for any help.

http://cypresshh.cakuun.com/index.php?id=14

Comment: `>` only works for its immediate children, and `ul` isn't a child of `a.selected`.

Comment: When I look at your link using firebug, no css is applied to a.selected. Can you show us how/where you css is defined?

Comment: What snuffn said, the ul element is not a child of a at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sub navigation is not a child of your selected link (>) but a direct sibling (+). You should use this instead:

<del>#main_nav ul li a.selected + ul { display: block; }</del>

```
#main_nav li a.selected + ul { display: block; }
```

Comment: You need to remove the first `ul`. But other than that, it's perfect. :)